# I can't click on my input when my window is too big

Tags: html, css, forms

I have made a form for my online CV where you can contact me, but first you need to enter the mail, subject and a message.
It all works perfectly but once my window reaches a certain size (1200px min width and 1200px min height), I gradually can't click on any of them until I can't fill in the form anymore.

Here is what the html look like :

```html
<div id="mail_form">
    <div id="m_f" class="jumbotron shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-lightgrey rounded">

        <h1 id="title_m_f" class="display-4"><b>Contactez moi</b></h1>

        <hr id="m_f_hr" class="my-4">

        <br>

        <form action="confirmMail.php" method="post" class="form-example" id="m_a_f">
        
            <div class="mail_a_form">
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
            </div>

            <div class="mail_a_form">
                <label for="object">Objet: </label>
                <input type="text" name="object" id="object">
            </div>

            <div class="mail_a_form">
                <label for="msg">Votre message: </label>
                <br>
                <textarea name="msg"  form="m_a_f" id="msg" placeholder="Ecrivez motre message ici : " required></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="mail_a_form">
                <input type="submit" value="Envoyer">
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the corresponding css (that might be messy since I am not a front dev)

```css
#mail_form{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -5%;
    left: 01%;
    width: 60%;
}
@media screen and (max-width:1199px) and (max-height:1200){
    #mail_form{
        margin-top: 15%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-height: 1200px) and (max-width:900px){
    #mail_form{
        margin-top: -70%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1200px){
    #mail_form{
        margin-top: 2%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-height: 1200px) and (min-width:1200px){
    #mail_form{
        margin-top: -20%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:900px) and (max-height:1000px){
    #mail_form{
        margin-top:25%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
    #mail_form{
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 10%;
        left: 05%;
        width: 80%;
    }
    
}
```

I've tried playing with the margins but nothing changed (and I did not changed them in the end or it won't display as I wanted.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `margin-top` properties from percentages to pixel values and you'll fix your problem

Instead of:

```
margin-top: 25%;
```

Do:

```
margin-top: 50px; // or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `@media screen` just set `#mail_form` style

```
#mail_form {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -120px;
  left: 01%;
  width: 60%;
}
```